# Using a video file as a 'webcam'

Tags: video, webcam

Is there anyway to make video0 point to a video file instead of an actual webcam? We're trying to hook something up using Skype that points to a prerecorded video file instead of a webcam.

Comment: Good idea .but dont fool your friends :)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/139239/fake-a-webcam-using-a-video-loopback-device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this WebcamStudio software could help:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/webcamstudio/

"WebcamStudio For GNU/Linux creates a virtual webcam that can mix several video sources together and can be used for live broadcasting"

Comment: I'll have a look at that, that could be perfect for what we need.